# Making the views(images) inside a linear layout dragable(android)

Tags: view, draggable

I have added Views(images) in a linear Layout and displayed it in a linear layout in this way:

```
 public void displayCard(ArrayList<Integer> aContent) {
    Point pnt = new Point();
 for(int i=0;i<13;i++)
     {
     pnt = Suffle.getCoOrdinate(aContent.get(i));
     imge=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
     LinearLayout bottomLinearLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomlinear);
     Bitmap orgbmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cards);
     Bitmap corp=Bitmap.createBitmap(orgbmp,Integer.valueOf(1+(2 + 144) *pnt.x),1+Integer.valueOf((2 + 194) * pnt.y), 144, 194);
     imge.setImageBitmap(corp);
     bottomLinearLayout.addView(imge, 60, 80);
     //bottomLinearLayout.addView(imge,i));
     }
```

Now i have to make each images added in the Linear layout draggable;how can i achieve this??